# Is there a way to apply Wordpress categories at the block level?

Tags: posts

My use case is as follows:

I have a database of videos and video transcripts. The transcripts have had a coding scheme applied to them, so that sections of the transcripts are categorized into different buckets. Wordpress categories and tags are pretty self-explanatory, but as far as I can tell, they only apply at the post level. Is there any way to apply a categorization scheme to the paragraph/block level?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

No, on a logical level applying categories to blocks is equivalent to applying categories to paragraphs and shortcodes. They can't be coaxed into it either via a custom object taxonomy as blocks don't have numeric unique IDs

I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve, but this is not the solution.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm trying to figure out if there's _any_ solution to my problem of adding tags to specific paragraphs or sentences, but it sounds like there might be no way to make discrete taggable objects out of parts of a post.

Comment: HTML classes, but you haven't shared what your actual problem is, just that tagging individual paragraphs might solve it. Either way you asked if blocks can be added to taxonomies/categories/tags and that's the question I answered. You might want to ask a new question if that's not what you really wanted to avoid confusion